# How to call validation function before confirm window?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a page where user prints data and then click button submit.

```
<form id="myForm" action="/validate-configuration" _method="post" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"
          onsubmit="return validateForm(this);">
    <table>
     ...
         <tr>
             <td></td>
                 <input 
                     type="submit" 
                     value="Obfuscate"
                     onclick="return doConfirm('<%=messageSource.getMessage("message.DatabasePage", null, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale())%>',
                       function yes() {
                             $('#myForm').submit();
                       },
                       function no() {});"
                  />
             </td>
             <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
    </table>
</form>

<div id="confirmBox" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="message"></div>
        <button type="button" class="yes">Yes</button>
        <button type="button" class="no">No</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

When a user clicks on submit first appear to confirm window. But I want to rich next behaviour. When something is not inputted first works validation function and after all input fields were completed appear to confirm button after click on submit button.

```
function validateForm(form) {
        return validateConfigurationSelect(form) && validateDBCredentials(form) && validateSalt(form);
    }

    function doConfirm(msg, yesFn, noFn) {
    var confirmBox = $("#confirmBox");
    confirmBox.find(".message").text(msg);
    confirmBox.find(".yes,.no").unbind().click(function () {
        confirmBox.hide();
    });
    confirmBox.find(".yes").click(yesFn);
    confirmBox.find(".no").click(noFn);
    confirmBox.show();
}
```

Answer: 
 make function doConfirm like this:

```
    function doConfirm(msg, yesFn, noFn, validationFunc) {
    if (validationFunc) {
        var confirmBox = $("#confirmBox");
        confirmBox.find(".message").text(msg);
        confirmBox.find(".yes,.no").unbind().click(function () {
            confirmBox.hide();
        });
        confirmBox.find(".yes").click(yesFn);
        confirmBox.find(".no").click(noFn);
        confirmBox.show();
    }
}
```

and in hmtl markup replace type of button form "submit" to "button" and add function:

```
input type="button" value="Obfuscate" onclick="
                doConfirm('<%=messageSource.getMessage("message.dialog.DatabasePage", null, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale())%>',
                function yes() {
                $('#myForm').submit();
                },
                function no() {
                },
                validateForm()
                );"/>
```

Also note that validateForm() should return boolean value.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all, you should not validate on the client (with Javascript) but on the server (with Java). Validating in javascript is bad because it is easy to by pass it.

BUT, to answer your question. Change your code into:

```
<input type="button" 
                     value="Obfuscate"
                     onclick="if (validateForm()) { return doConfirm('<%=messageSource.getMessage("message.DatabasePage", null, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale())%>',
                       function yes() {
                             $('#myForm').submit();
                       },
                       function no() {}); } else { showErrors() } "
                  />
```

You don't need to pass the "form" argument in validateForm() because you can retrieve the values with `document.getElementBy("")` etc.

So to summarize:

1. user presses Save button (which is not submit type but just button type button)
2. `validateForm()` is called
3. if true then call doConfirm(), if OK button then  `$('#myForm').submit();`
4. if false then display some errors

Comment: But it doesn't resolve the problem, because functions in js runs asynchronously. But i want if some field are not specified, confirm window doesn't appear, just label appear near the field. And when user specified all fields and click button submit than and only than confirm window appears and if user click yes on confirm window than execution continues.

Comment: It will solve your problem but you have to fix the asynchronous problem. Or did you expect me to do everything for you? Look at the doConfirm()..You are calling the yes and no functions immediately instead of just binding the callback functions..

Comment: Good for you! Don't share it with the rest and don't say thanks to people trying to help..

Comment: I saw your disturbance, but I'm at work. And can't answer.